# If even function then ...

Tags: induction, taylor-expansion, even-and-odd-functions

We let {$a_n$}$_{n\in N}$ be $a_n$=$\frac{f^{n}(0)}{n!}$.
I have to show that if $f$ is an even function so is $a_{2n-1}$$=0$ for all n$\in$N.
How can I show it? By induction maybe? Can anyone give a hint?
If we try induction:

Induction start:
n=1:
$$f(x)=f(-x)$$
$$f'(x)=-f'(x)$$
$$x=0 ->2f'(0)=0->f'(0)=0$$

Induction assumption is then:
$$f^{2n-1}(0)=0$$

But now I can't move on my own. What to do then?

Comment: could u show us your attempt ?

Comment: Now I have added my attempt

Answer (score 0):

**Hints/Outline:**

- If $f$ is even, then $f(-x) = f(x)$. Equivalently, $f(x) - f(-x) = 0$.
- Try differentiating this equation with respect to $x$ an odd number of times, call it $2n-1$ times. Then you get $f^{(2n-1)}(x) + f^{(2n-1)}(-x) = 0$. Be careful with the signs for the $f(-x)$ term's derivative as you verify this yourself.
- Let $x=0$. This will imply that $f^{(2n-1)}(0) = 0$. This in turn implies what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** you may look this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/741716/156150)

Here is a simple proof:

We know that the derivative of an odd function is even and the derivative of an even function is odd. Obviously, an odd function evaluated at $0$ must vanish, otherwise we would get a contradiction. Consequently, if $f(x)$ is odd, then $f^{(n)}(x)$ is either even or odd. In particular, if $n$ is even, then $f^{(n)}(x)$ is odd and as a result $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$. Hence, the Maclaurin series expansion of $f(x)$ can consists only of the odd degree terms.